# How to know which checkbox is selected?

Tags: matlab, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes. The tags are '`car`' and '`bycycle`'. They have strings declared as *'check1' and 'check2'*.

When the button pressed, I want to know which checkbox is checked.

I only know this way:

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
clc;
car = get(handles.car,'Value')
bycycle = get(handles.bycycle,'Value')

if car==1
..

elseif bycycle ==1
..
```

But i want to know if there's another way without the `get(handles.sometags,'Value')`, because with that approach I have to manually declare `handles.car`, `handles.bycycle`, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 2 checkboxes. The tags are 'car' and 'bycycle'

then why can't you do simply this : ( tags are mandatory, they represents a UI state, with lot of "medata" data )

```
get( handles.car, 'Value' )

get( handles.bycycle, 'Value' )
```

You don't have to declare extra variables for those, to set default values simply use `set` functions.

`handles` have all useful fields, you can see those using

`assignin( 'base', 'handles', handles );`

Comment: Hi . I mean in that way I've to know `car` in the `handles.car`,

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup `handles` is available in all callback

Comment: Hi, how do I check like  `if some_handles.hasATagWhichIs=='car'`?.I've upvoted.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup not sure why you want that, but you can use `isfield(some_handles,'car')` to check that.